# Subquery in PL/SQL returning NO_DATA_FOUND

Tags: sql, exception, plsql, subquery

A PL/SQL query I am looking at uses a subquery when determining a count of records:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO v_seqn
FROM SIPR.KDX KDX
WHERE KDX.KDX_STUC NOT IN ( SELECT ADD1.ADD_ADID
                            FROM SIPR.MEN_ADD ADD1
                            WHERE ADD1.ADD_ADID = KDX.KDX_STUC)
AND KDX.KDX_STUC = v_stud_id
AND KDX.KDX_SITS = 'A';
```

If the subquery returns no records, will this cause a NO_DATA_FOUND exception which can be handled, or is it perfectly valid and will simply return a null for the "NOT IN" clause of the main query and result in a count of 0.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running it? The `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception will not be thrown in this case, and `COUNT` will return `0`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the environment to test it myself and am trying to assist a colleague. There are no PLSQL experts here sadly, so I'm appealing to the experts on SO. :-)

Comment: I see, in this case, as I said, the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception will not be thrown. It would if you were `SELECTing` ... `INTO` some variables, and that query would yield no results, then you would get `NO_DATA_FOUND`. In your query, when the subquery returns no rows, the `COUNT(*)` will return `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change anything. If the subquery returns no rows, then the main query will have no results, but since it is a count query without any `group by` or `having clauses` it will always return exactly one row with exactly one value, which might be `0`.

It will never return null and it will not give you a NO_DATA_FOUND exception. The NO_DATA_FOUND exception is not an SQL but a PL/SQL error that occurs when you try to `select` a value `into` a variable, but the (main) select doesn't return any rows.

Answer (score 0):

This will fetch all rows from SIPR.KDX KDX with the other satisfying conditions 
in the where clause but a mutually exclusive result of your subquery. This is
similar A-B-C in set language where A is your table, B is your subquery and C is
all other satisfying conditions in the where clause.

Try to use outer join

```
SELECT
      COUNT ( * )
INTO
      V_SEQN
FROM
          (SELECT
                *
           FROM
                SIPR.KDX KDX
           WHERE
                KDX.KDX_STUC = V_STUD_ID
                AND KDX.KDX_SITS = 'A') TABLE1
      LEFT OUTER JOIN
          SIPR.MEN_ADD ADD1
      ON TABLE1.KDX_STUC = ADD1.ADD_ADID
WHERE
      ADD1.ADD_ADID IS NULL;
```

Or using not exists

```
SELECT
      COUNT ( * )
INTO
      V_SEQN
FROM
          (SELECT
                *
           FROM
                SIPR.KDX KDX
           WHERE
                KDX.KDX_STUC = V_STUD_ID
                AND KDX.KDX_SITS = 'A') TABLE1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS  
        (SELECT   
               1  
          FROM  
               SIPR.MEN_ADD ADD1  
          WHERE  
               TABLE1.KDX_STUC = ADD1.ADD_ADID)
```